# store multiple images vectors into rows of a matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a folder which contains 200 BMP images, I am reading all the images, converting each image into a vector and then trying to store these image vectors into a matrix. Following is the code which is self-explanatory, though it looks quite right however when i run the script it gives me the following error.

```
Error in Readallimages (line 16)
immat(437580,k)=imtovector 
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`

myFolder = 'C:\Users\Sana\Desktop\DermoscopyImages';
if ~isdir(myFolder)
errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', 
myFolder);
uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
return;
end
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.bmp');
bmpFiles = dir(filePattern);
immat=zeros(437580,200);

  for k = 1:length(bmpFiles)
      baseFileName = bmpFiles(k).name;
      fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
      fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
      imageArray = rgb2gray(imread(fullFileName)); %Read images
      imtovector=double(imageArray(:));      %Convert 2D image to 1D vector
      immat(437580,k)=imtovector           %Store image vector to matrix
      imshow(imageArray);  % Display image.
      drawnow; % Force display to update immediately.
  end`
```

Any type of help in this regard would highly be appreciated.
Thanks inadvance

Comment: I assume your vectorized image is of length 437580. Replace the line before `imshow` to `immat(:,k) = imtovector;`.

Comment: Sir, I tried that, it still gives me the same dimensions mismatch error.

Comment: what size is `imtovector`? it's definitely not 437580 then.

Comment: no Sir. it has the same size as mentioned.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with this code, although I have calculated the dimensions of the image and the matrix many times in order to clear any ambiguity.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Run `dbstop if error` in command line and run the code, it will stop when you get the error, and give you a breakpoint. Then you can check the dimensions using `whos`.

Comment: The line `immat(437580,k)=imtovector` gives you that error because the dimension of `imtovector` is not 1x1. You're trying to store multiple values at a single index (i.e. at 437580th row and kth column) which is not possible. What is the reason behind writing `437580`? Where does this number come from? What is the size of `imtovector`? Is the size same for all the images? If yes, kedarps suggestion in the first comment should work. If no, you would've to use cell arrays.

Comment: @SardarUsama , actually 437580 is the size of my image when I convert the image into a vector, and the matrix to which I want to save the vector is of size 437580x200. I already have defined the vector and matrix size, what I am trying to do is storing the vector into first row of matrix and then second and so on all the 200 images into matrix. each row containing single image.

Comment: The sizes of images are not same after using _imread_, you need to either resize all of them to same dimensions using _imresize_ or use cellarrays.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I did the same and now its fine. Thank you so much all for your precious suggestions and time.